# Convert mysql in Linq Lambda

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, lambda

I am trying to convert an expression to lambda, but I can't do it correctly because the result executing it in the database and in the lambda query gives different result.

**SQL Query:**

```
select tab1.* from table1 tab1 inner join table2 tab2 on tab1.id = tab2.id
```

That query gives me 16 rows but I can't make a lambda expression that doesn't return an empty list.

**My Lambda expression:**

```
var query = table1.Join(table2, tab1=> tab1.id, tab2=> tab2.id, (tab1, tab2) => new {tab1}).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you share the lambda expression which you have created?

Comment: Are you getting `query.Count` = 0 ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes

Comment: That's strange... join code of C# is correct.. you can change `new {tab1}` to just `tab1`. Did you verify if the C# code is querying the right database server and database?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i verified that. I don't  understand either where is the problem. Changing new {tab1} for tab1 the result is the same

Comment: Apart from the "new", the LINQ seems ok. To debug, create a small console object, with two Lists, containing some table1 and table2 rows. Experiment with several list contents, for example Both Lists contain one element with same value for `Id`. What is the result? And if you give one of these lists a second element with the same `Id`? And if both lists have two elements with all same Id? If you want as result a sequence of Tab1 rows, change your LINQ query: `(tab1, tab2) => tab1)`, leave out the `new`